# How do I secure my VNC for access via iOS?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Google Compute Engine, the instance is running VNC which it is up and running using :

```
vncserver -SecurityTypes=VeNCrypt,TLSVnc
```

But when I try to use VNC Viewer on iOS, it gives me an error saying:

> "not supported encryption"

I am open to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

On the remote computer you should update VNC to the latest version or disable/change the VNC Viewer Encryption parameter to either `Server`, `PreferOn` or `PreferOff`.

To better understand more error messages you can check the [error codes documentation](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/connect-error-ref.html).